# How to write google script to automatically call data from a google folder drive that contains a CSV file into one Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write a google script that will allow me to go into my google drive folder called "MeadJohsnon" and pull 'Temperature Calibration.csv' to google sheets. I have never used google script before. Currently I have the "Save Email and Attachment" Add-ons. This add-on is pulling .cvs files that my team is sending me from the field. They use "TapForms" and then send the form via email to my gmail. So, I got the email sending that attachment to my google drive but I need help with the script, so Drive will automatically get those .cvs files and put the information into one google sheet. I say ONE google sheet because although I have a team sending in forms, all the forms have the same information on them.

This is what I have done so far. The fourth line gives me a

```
function loadingCSV() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
 sht.clearContents();
 var data = loadFile();
 var dataA =Utilities.parseCsv(data);
 var rng = sht.getRange(1, 1, dataA.length, dataA[0].length);
 rng.setValues(dataA);
}
```

I would just like feedback on how to fix my error or what I could do instead. As stated this is my first time using google script, my specialty is ASP.net lol not script. Thank you.

Comment: Is 'Temperature_Calibration_csv_id' defined anywhere? i.e. var Temperature_Calibration_csv_id = 'hsdojsdajkhadfsad89ojfsadasdfklsad89';

Comment: No, that line is not defined anywhere! What value should i assign to it?

Comment: The ID of the google sheet you are trying to add the data to.

Comment: Thank you, that is the part I was confused on. I did not know where to locate the ID. It is in the URL of the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function loadingCSV() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sht.clearContents();
  var data = loadFile();
  var dataA =Utilities.parseCsv(data);
  var rng = sht.getRange(1, 1, dataA.length, dataA[0].length);
  rng.setValues(dataA);
}

function loadFile(filename,folderID)
{
  var filename = (typeof(filename) !== 'undefined')? filename : 'Temperature Calibration.csv';
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : '0B8m9xkDP_TJxUUlueHhXOWJMbjg';
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var file = fldr.getFilesByName(filename);
  var s = '';
  while(file.hasNext())
  {
    var fi = file.next();
    var target = fi.getName();
    if(target == filename)
    {
      s = fi.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

Okay this will append the files to the active spreadsheet you'll probably have to open the spreadsheet by id and use getSheetByName to get the sheet you want because this spreadsheet probably won't be active all the time when the trigger is running.  I assume the the files all end in .csv.  I rename them to .old after reading the data so that the program won't read them multiple times.

```
function appendingCSV() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var drng = sht.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = drng.getLastRow();
  var data = loadFiles();
  var dataA =Utilities.parseCsv(data);
  if(dataA.length>0)
  {
    var rng = sht.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, dataA.length, dataA[0].length);
    rng.setValues(dataA);
  }
  else
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No Data Returned from LoadFiles');
  }
}

function loadFiles(folderID)
{
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : '0B8m9xkDP_TJxUUlueHhXOWJMbjg';
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var s='';
  var re = /^.*\.csv$/i;
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    if(filename.match(re))
    {
      s += file.getBlob().getDataAsString() + '\n';
      file.setName(filename.slice(0,-3) + 'old');
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Cooper. I am trying to get "Temperature Calibration.csv into my drive folder named MeadJohnson into the google sheet file name of Mead_Johnson. This is what I filled in on the code you sent me, which is helpful but not returning the results I am looking for. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: var data = loadFile('Temperature Calibration.csv');
  var dataA =Utilities.parseCsv(data);
  var rng = sht.getRange(1, 1, dataA.length, dataA[0].length)
  rng.setValues(dataA);
}

function loadFile(filename,folderID)
{
  var filename = (typeof(filename) !== 'Mead_Johnson')? filename : DefaultFileName;
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== '0B8m9xkDP_TJxUUlueHhXOWJMbjg')? folderID : DataFolderID;
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B8m9xkDP_TJxUUlueHhXOWJMbjg');
  var file = fldr.getFilesByName('Mead_Johnson');

Comment: I have an Add-on pulling the .csv files from gmail to my MeadJohnson folder in google drive. Within that folder I have a blank Mead_Johnson google sheet. I want to automate the process of those .csv files going into the Mead_Johnson google sheet without me having to update it manually. Is this possible?

Comment: I modified the code with your variables.  Yes you can do it automatically with a [timed based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: Worked perfectly. I am going to put the timed trigger in there now. Thank you

Comment: Question, what would you change 'Temperature Calibration.csv' to if you have other .csv files coming into the folder but aren't titled 'Temperature Calibration.csv'?

Comment: Do you want the other files to overwrite the data?

Comment: I would like it to be added with the data, not replace it. So, the .csv files that are coming in are forms entered in by my field service technicians. The form will have the same questions but the answers will vary but when they submit them, I want all of those .cvs to be inputed into the Mead_Johnson spreadsheet. Does that make sense?

Comment: Some of the metrics are like StartDate/Time and which technician submitted it. Then a lot more after that, but thats the gist of it.

Comment: Do you have a link to your spreadsheet that you can share with us.  So I can modify this so that it has half a chance of working the first time.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f9HEwikMxm5sJzzRh_-etBxXzL0NpK47i9LtoZVCv_0/edit#gid=0

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f9HEwikMxm5sJzzRh_-etBxXzL0NpK47i9LtoZVCv_0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, above is the shareable link

Comment: So which of these fields is in the file and which do you add after they arrive.

Comment: All of those fields will be present when they send their individual responses in from the form. I just want it to be able to automatically update there responses with those fields.. going down the spreadsheet so i can then open another tab that shows charts based on the metrics i want to see from those fields.

Comment: Read the comments with the new code in the bottom section.  Some of it is appropriate to running off of the trigger.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will give it a shot. Renaming them to .old is good advice as well I didn't think about that. You are correct that they will all end with .csv. Thanks again Cooper

Comment: Cooper, look at the edits i made above in the code. Line 7 (var rng = sht.getRange(1, 1, dataA.length, dataA[0].length); ) is giving me a TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. All of the sudden, do you know why?

Comment: I assume the function your dealing with is the loadingCSV function.  The error would indicate to me that there is no content in the dataA.  But more importantly don't you wish to use appendingCSV.  I thought you wanted to append data not replace.

Comment: Perhaps we should continue this in a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147074/how-to-write-google-script-to-automatically-call-data-from-a-google-folder-drive)

Comment: I would love to respond in the chat room but since I am new and don't have a reputation of 20 I cannot reply to you ha ha

Comment: Do you have an email where I could reach out to you?

Comment: I just tried giving you access to the room.  Give it another shot.  I'm not that experienced with using these chat rooms.

Comment: You definitely have access to the [room now](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147074/how-to-write-google-script-to-automatically-call-data-from-a-google-folder-drive).

Comment: I have access, but I cannot reply to you because I don't have a reputation of 20.

Comment: I just gave you write access to the room.  I'll check it out and see if I can overcome this issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have write access now.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think we can get around this. On the FAQ it say's you need 20. I took out the loadingCsv function and added what you said and deleted all the files and put them back into the folder and ran it and it worked. Plus changed all of them to .old. I think we are good!

Comment: The reply button is still grayed our, and the same message is present at the bottom: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: Okay great.  Sorry about the chat room issue.  I'll try to learn more about that for the future.

Comment: That is fine! Thank you for your help

Comment: Cooper, I got other .csv files coming in. They imported but not exactly the way I imagined. I was going to ask is there a way we can tweak the Script? This is the shareable link with the updaated forms inside. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f9HEwikMxm5sJzzRh_-etBxXzL0NpK47i9LtoZVCv_0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to not duplicate the headers when the new .csv files are imported, so they get added into the sheet in sequential order without adding the headers. . like row 2 and 6 show. Also, sequential to make the dates go in order in column A. Another question I had was, do you know what happened in line 14? I have deleted and re entered the new data in and every time that happens. Otherwise it is pretty solid.

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to post a new questions and include your current code with a link to any relevent spreadsheets.

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724482/using-google-script-to-import-csv-files-into-an-existing-google-sheet-formatti> new question