# Using google script to import .csv files into an existing google sheet. Formatting issues.

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Is there a way to not duplicate the headers when the new .csv files are imported from my one drive folder into the existing google sheet? I want the .csv files to be added to the existing sheet in sequential order without adding the headers...example - like row 2 and 19 show. Also, sequential to make the dates go in order in column A. Another question I had was, do you know what happened in line 10? I have deleted and re entered the new data in and every time that happens. This is my script I have now. This is a shareable link to the sheet and what it looks like. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f9HEwikMxm5sJzzRh_-etBxXzL0NpK47i9LtoZVCv_0/edit?usp=sharing This is the script I have right now.

```
function appendingCSV() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
 var drng = sht.getDataRange();
 var lastRow = drng.getLastRow();
 var data = loadFiles();
 var dataA =Utilities.parseCsv(data);
if(dataA.length>0)
{
 var rng = sht.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, dataA.length, dataA[0].length);
 rng.setValues(dataA);
}
else
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No Data Returned from LoadFiles');
}
}

function loadFiles(folderID)
{
 var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : 
 '0B8m9xkDP_TJxUUlueHhXOWJMbjg';
var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
var files = fldr.getFiles();
 var s='';
 var re = /^.*\.csv$/i;
 while (files.hasNext())
 {
  var file = files.next();
  var filename = file.getName();
  if(filename.match(re))
  {
    s += file.getBlob().getDataAsString() + '\n';
    file.setName(filename.slice(0,-3) + 'old');
  }
 }
 return s;
}

function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
// Trigger every Friday at 09:00.
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .timeBased()
    .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
    .atHour(9)
    .create();
 }
```

Comment: Just splice the first row off?

Comment: How do you do that in the script? I didn't think about that.

Comment: [First google hit on "javascript splice"](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Comment: Okay, how do I incorporate the splice into my current code, so that when future .csv files get imported only the information gets put into the sheet? Without the repeating headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loadFiles() script.  Try changing it to something like this.

```
function loadFiles(folderID)
{
  //var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : 'Your_folder_id';
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : 'Your_folder_id';
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var s='';
  var re = /^.*\.csv$/i;
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    if(filename.match(re))
    {
      s+=file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split('\n').splice(0,1).join('\n') + '\n';
      //s += file.getBlob().getDataAsString() + '\n';
      file.setName(filename.slice(0,-3) + 'old');
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

You may have to play with this a little.  I'm not sure if the last '\n' is needed or not and I'm not that great at chaining so many operations.  But you need to remove the headers from each file.  You could write a local script that you give to your techs that strips off the headers at the origin and in that case then go back to the way it is now.

Comment: I will play around with it and see if I can get it to work! I will get back to you. The local script isn't a bad idea but the application they use to submit forms requires headers so that the techs are inputting correct data types and what not. The script would be able to manipulate the headers before it goes into my gmail. . . then to one drive folder then to the sheet? When would the script engage their forms?

Comment: I made a mistake on the splice and I just changed it to splice(0,1) so I think that means it will remove the first item.

Comment: Cooper - The first splice worked better. I set the header in the google sheet manually and when i run the script it puts the .csv files in there without the headers and right under my manually inputted headers. The 0,1 splice just inputted the headers only. I also did remove that last (+'\n'). My last question is do you know what could be wrong with row 9? I dont know why it keeps putting that information in there like that. Maybe it is a format issue with the forms application i am having my techs send in. As well... you see the gap between row 15-18 it seperates the two forms..can erase gap?

Comment: <https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f9HEwikMxm5sJzzRh_-etBxXzL0NpK47i9LtoZVCv_0/edit?usp=sharing>

Comment: Dont mind the gap. I know what the gap is. Just row 9. Maybe it is format and I just delete it and see if it continues to do that with other data received by the .csv files.